# How to trace the request path of the form?

Tags: php, forms, security, request

Briefly I want to trace the url requests path of the $_POST. If you have a script in http://example.com/myscript.php i want to accept request only from http://example.com/myfrom.html, because if i write a form from on my pc and put the link in the from to the site (), he accept the requests.
I just dont wanna accept request from other servers. How is possible?

Comment: To let you kniow, that's quite impossible. As a matter of fact, a filled form always being posted from your pc.

Comment: have you heard of TamperData?  You can always modify a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attempting to track the source of requests, this is more often handled by generating a random value with your form and storing it in a hidden input field. When you receive the form with `script.php`, you verify that the random value submitted by the form matches the one you have stored in `$_SESSION`.  This ensures that the visiting user must have loaded the form first.

Your form is currently .html, but you would need to make it a PHP script instead

#### form.php:

```
// Create a random token in $_SESSION
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(time() . rand());

<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>' name='token' />
```

#### script.php

```
// Verify a valid token was submitted
session_start();
if ($_POST['token'] !== $_SESSION['token']) {
  // invalid post
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if he copy the hide field all is the same.

Comment: @user1091156 No, because the hidden field is regenerated for each user on each pageload. He must visit the form first, and if he doesn't submit it from there it doesn't really matter, because he must visit the form again to retrieve the new hidden field again. The field is different for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` but this can be forged.
What you want to do sounds like preventing [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). In order to do this you include a unique generated key in the myform.html as a hidden field (must be a myform.php then) and check in myscript.php if it is the right key. So you can be sure if the request has been submitted by your form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discourage some casual user from posting from someone else's site to yours, you might be able to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.  The browser sends a "referer" along with most requests, which in many cases is the page that the user clicked to get there.  It's definitely not foolproof, though -- a browser (or a bot) can fudge it at will, and some browsers (or plugins for such browsers) will do so on purpose.  The users of those browsers are generally pretty big on privacy, and you're not that special.  They'll probably prefer going elsewhere rather than disabling their privacy stuff for you.

You could require a session variable set in order to post, but that's rather trivial to get around too.  `<img src="http://your.site/yourForm.php" width="1" height="1">` would be enough to get a session variable set.

A hidden form field sounds doable, but i could write a script to fetch your form, grab the hidden field, and insert it into my form.  It'd only be useful in conjunction with a session variable that says what ID to expect...and that gets really wacky if people use the Back button in certain ways.  It'd also fail if i proxy the request (ie: the user talks to my server, which requests a form from you (and gets a session ID), and then when the user posts to my site, i post to yours using the session ID and hidden values that you sent me).  About the only way around that is HTTPS, and even that's useless if the user is expecting the form to come from me and not you.

Basically, there's no way short of a combination of the above stuff plus a decent CAPTCHA to *prevent* other sites from posting to your form.  And even that has its weaknesses.  The best you can do is make it a pain...and that'll make it a pain for some percentage of your users as well.  Your best bet is to make sure the script that accepts the post verifies its contents, and not care where the request came from.